# Need to display a message when chart not having data in birt report

Tags: birt

I have daily incident report which consist charts and incidents details.

When ever there is no data or incident the charts are left with blank in the report.

I want put a message in those block of charts.

Any body can help me  in these.

Note : This issue is raised based on Chart display, if there is no data available instead of blank it should display the message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display "No Data" message when table is empty in BIRT Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425876/display-no-data-message-when-table-is-empty-in-birt-report)

Comment: @Miki Dominique is suggesting in the comment of their answer that the two questions are different enough that their answer does not fit there.  So this would not be a duplicate, thoughts?

Comment: @JamesJenkins moderators will decide

Answer (score 1):

Whereas you could make use of the regular "visibilty" property as suggested by Miki, there is also an out-of-the-box feature for handling this in charts:

[image]

You can see this example in action [here](http://www.visioneo.org/economic-country-detail): select a country which does not provide many economic data such "Andorra", and compare it with "Cayman islands": you would see this "No data" message in the second chart

Comment: You should include this answer on the question linked to by Miki, this one is likely to closed as dupe.

Comment: @james i considered this however the topic pointed by miki consists in hiding a table, when my answer only works for charts

Comment: For the below version chart property "visibility" is avaliable  is Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.7.1
Build id: M20110909-1335 but I'm using this version Eclipse Platform 
Version: 3.4.2
Build id: M20090211-1700 for Maximo 7.5.0, any suggetion